# Can't use attachInterrupt in a library

Tags: arduino, static-libraries, interrupt

I'm writing a simple library for an ultrasonic distance sensor and thought i'd try using interrupts.

However i can't set my functions in the `attachCallback` method properly.

I want `HCSR04Interrupt::echoHigh()` and `HCSR04Interrupt::echoLow()` called when the pin goes high and low respectively.

I've Googled this to no avail. The Ardiuno IDE says the following:

```
./Arduino/libraries/HCSR04/HCSR04Interrupt.cpp: In member function 'void HCSR04Interrupt::getDistance()':
./Arduino/libraries/HCSR04/HCSR04Interrupt.cpp:31: error: argument of type 'void (HCSR04Interrupt::)()' does not match 'void (*)()'
./Arduino/libraries/HCSR04/HCSR04Interrupt.cpp: In member function 'void HCSR04Interrupt::echoHigh()':
./Arduino/libraries/HCSR04/HCSR04Interrupt.cpp:47: error: argument of type 'void (HCSR04Interrupt::)()' does not match 'void (*)()'
```

Here is my header:

```
#ifndef _HCSR04Interrupt_
#define _HCSR04Interrupt_

#include "Arduino.h"

#define HCSR04_CM_FACTOR 58.0
#define HCSR04_IN_FACTOR 148.0
#define HCSR04_CM_MODE 0
#define HCSR04_IN_MODE 1

class HCSR04Interrupt {
  public:
    double distance;

    HCSR04Interrupt(int trigger_pin, int echo_pin, void (*callback)());

    void setUnits(int units);

    void getDistance();
  private:
    int _trigger_pin;
    int _echo_pin;
    int _units;
    unsigned long _micros_start;
    void (*_callback)();

    void initialize();
    void echoHigh();
    void echoLow();
};

#endif
```

And my implementation (not complete since i cant get past the attachInterrupt step):

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "HCSR04Interrupt.h"

HCSR04Interrupt::HCSR04Interrupt(int trigger_pin, int echo_pin, void (*callback)()) {
  _trigger_pin = trigger_pin;
  _echo_pin = echo_pin;
  _callback = callback;

  initialize();
}

void HCSR04Interrupt::setUnits(int units) {
  _units = units;
}

void HCSR04Interrupt::initialize() {
  pinMode(_trigger_pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(_echo_pin, INPUT);

  digitalWrite(_trigger_pin, LOW);
}

void HCSR04Interrupt::getDistance() {
  //Listen for the RISING interrupt
  attachInterrupt(_echo_pin - 2, echoHigh, RISING);

  //The trigger pin should be pulled high,
  digitalWrite(_trigger_pin, HIGH);

  //for 10 us.
  delayMicroseconds(20);

  //Then reset it.
  digitalWrite(_trigger_pin, LOW);
}

void HCSR04Interrupt::echoHigh() {
  _micros_start = micros();

  detachInterrupt(_echo_pin - 2);
  attachInterrupt(_echo_pin - 2, echoLow, FALLING);
}

void HCSR04Interrupt::echoLow() {
  detachInterrupt(_echo_pin - 2);

  unsigned long us = micros() - _micros_start;

  distance = us;

  (*_callback)();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

So the **compiler** (not the IDE) tells you exactly what's wrong:

```
argument of type 'void (HCSR04Interrupt::)()' does not match 'void (*)()
```

So, while `attachInterrupt()` takes a function pointer of type `void (*)()`, you're trying to pass it a **non-static member function,** which you can't. You can try making the member function `static` and casting:

```
static void echoHigh();

// ...

attachInterrupt(_echo_pin - 2, reinterpret_cast<void (*)()>(&echoHigh), RISING);
```

Comment: attachInterrupt has requirements that the function it points to be STATIC. and that then causes all member functions upwards from attachInterrupt to be static. I have done this, successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Arduino interrupt handlers can only be functions. You are trying make **method of an object** an interrupt handler.  Hence the compiler complains.

To be more precise about it, object methods are like functions, but it is as if they take a "hidden" parameter, which specifies the object instance. Therefore, they actually have different type signatures from plain functions. This disallows one to pass a method pointer when what a function is looking for is a plain function pointer.

The solution is to move your `echoHigh()` and `echoLow()` out of the `HCSR04Interrupt` class, and make them plain functions.

Answer (score 1):

As I stumbled upon this question and it hasn't had an accepted answer, I write what I found, which worked for me:

The interrupt has to be called by a global wrapper. This wrapper needs to call a `handleInterupt` function of the class. Therefore it has to know the class. This can be done by storing it in a global variable. If multiple instances of the class should be used, multiple such global variables have to be used. But as the interrupt pins are just a few you can write a global variable and function for every pin:

```
MyClass theInstance_pin3 = NULL;
MyClass theInstance_pin7 = NULL;

// Somewhere, fill in an initialized copy of MyClass,
// and set theInstance_pin3 or theInstance_pin7 to it

void ISR_3()
{
   if (theInstance_pin3)
       theInstance_pin3->handleInterrupt();
}
void ISR_7()
{
   if (theInstance_pin7)
       theInstance_pin7->handleInterrupt();
}
```

as a reference see: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=41713.0
or http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=160101.0

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by making a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern%20singleton) base class which represents the hardware as a whole (which kinda makes sense in this situation anyway).

Any function pointers can then be passed to the sub-component class, and handled by the singleton, whose member variables and methods are all static.

Example headers (untested):

```
// Sub-component
class LampButton {
public:
    LampButton(int pin, void(*pushHandler)());
}

// Sub-component
class LampLed {
public:
    LampLed(int pin);
    void toggle();
}

// Singleton represents the hardware in it's entirety
class Lamp {
public:
    // Call this instead of a constructor
    static void initialize(int buttonPin, int ledPin);

    // Function implemented inline for clarity - don't do this
    static void handleButtonPush() {
        led.toggle();
    }

private:
    static LampButton button;
    static LampLed led;
}
```